# Zend Form - problem rendering individual elements

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have this simplified form:

```
        $this->form = new \Zend_Form();
        $this->form->setAction($request->currentPath());
        $this->form->setMethod('post');


        $this->form->addElement('text', 'firstName', array(
            'label' => 'First name: ',
        ));
```

and I want to render the element individually in my view page. Like so:

```
        <?php echo $form->firstName->renderViewHelper() ?>
```

But I keep getting this error:

**Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Zend_Form_Decorator_Exception' with message 'ViewHelper decorator cannot render without a registered view object'.

What am I doing wrong? I have pretty much followed the Zend Documentation on this page:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.form.decorators.individual.html

Sincerely,
Why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the form object after creating it in one of your controllers to your view script to render the form elements.

```
$this->view->form = $form;
```

And in your view script do something like

```
echo $this->form->firstName->renderViewHelper();
```